# Felony codes in Frank Artiles fake campaign case in Miami-Dade

Tags: criminal-law, florida, court, elections, campaign

Frank Artiles, a former Florida state representative and senator, was charged with felonies in connection to a scam candidate scheme in Miami Dade County. There was a general question asked about the legality of fake campaigns over in politics, and [one answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/69356/7226) mentioned this case. Commenters seemed to suspect that Mr. Artiles is not charged because a "fake campaign" would be illegal (on what counts? Lying in politics?) but because more specific campaign finance and election laws were violated in the process. I looked up the case, F-21-004768-B / 13-2021-CF-004768-B000-XX, in the publicly searchable [case database of Miami Dade](https://www2.miami-dadeclerk.com/cjis/CaseSearch.aspx).

The case, which is pending, lists the following charges:

> CAM CONTR/ACC 2>CONT
>
> ELECTION CODE/FALSE
>
> VOTER REG/FLS INFO

While "Voter reg[istration]/f[a]ls[e] info" seems self explanatory, the other ones are not, to me. What precisely has Mr. Artiles been charged with?

Comment: That case number can't be correct, B000 is not a valid entry in field 4

Comment: I'm not sure but judging what the press are saying: CAM CONTR/ACC could be CAMpaign CONTRibutions / ACCounting offences; and an [ELECTION CODE](https://library.municode.com/fl/miami_-_dade_county/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PTIIICOOR_CH12EL_S12-5CACOEX) violation. Here's a list of the charges etc:  https://www2.miami-dadeclerk.com/cjis/CaseSearch.aspx

Comment: @Trish There is a court case number, F-21-004768-B, and the quoted state case number.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"CAM CONTR/ACC 2>CONT" refers to [F.S. 106.08(7)(B)](https://law.justia.com/codes/florida/2014/title-ix/chapter-106/section-106.08/), under which Artiles is charged with "making or receiving **two or more** **cam**paign **contr**ibutions over or in excess of the limits," as well as engaging in a conspiracy to do so.

"ELECTION CODE/FALS" refers to [F.S. 104.011(1)](https://law.justia.com/codes/florida/2014/title-ix/chapter-104/section-104.011/), under which Artiles is charged with "swearing or affirming **fal**sely to any oath or affirmation, or willfully procuring another person to swear or affirm falsely to an oath or affirmation, in connection with or arising out of voting or **election**s"

"VOTER REG/FLS INFO" refers to [F.S. 104.011(1)](https://law.justia.com/codes/florida/2014/title-ix/chapter-104/section-104.011/), under which Artiles is charged with aiding and abetting another to "submit any **false** **voter reg**istration **info**rmation."

More information about the factual basis for the charges is available in the arrest warrant [here](https://www.miamiherald.com/latest-news/article250029104.ece/BINARY/Artiles%20%26%20Rodriguez%20Warrant%20(redacted).pdf).

Comment: Good detective work.

Answer (score 6):

[Ballotpedia](https://ballotpedia.org/Frank_Artiles#Campaign_finance_charges_.28March_2021.29) describes the alleged crimes as:

> 1. one count of false swearing in connection with voting or elections
> 2. one count of making or receiving campaign contributions over or in excess of limits
> 3. one count of conspiracy to make or receive two or more campaign contributions over or in excess of limits.

It is hard to pinpoint which of the three is exactly which. To the best of my deduction, it appears that charge 2 (campaign contributions in excess of limits) would be under Cam Contr/Acc, as that seems to match best with Campaign Contributions & Accounting. Charge 3 appears to be most likely the Voter Registration/Falsification of Information, while the conspiracy most likely is the Election Code/False [Swearing]

Comment: Ah, "CAM" is "campaign".